# hibernate database query returns null value

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

In my database I have a table named user,

I want to fetch the user_id,name where email=? and password=?

so,I have :--

```
public User Signin(User user) {
        String hql = "select user_id,name from  users  where email = :email and password = :password";
        SQLQuery query =  (SQLQuery) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(hql)
                .setParameter("email", user.getEmail())
                .setParameter("password", user.getPassword());

            return (User) query.uniqueResult();

    }
```

but it returns null value.why??

I also have used:--

```
public User Signin(User user) {

        String hql = "select user_id,name from  User  where email = :email and password = :password1";
        Query query =  (Query) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql)
                .setParameter("email", user.getEmail())
                .setParameter("password1", user.getPassword());


            return (User) query.uniqueResult(); 
        }
```

It is also returning null value..why?

Comment: the email and password you are passing might not available in db.

Comment: Did you try executing the SQL-Query directly with a mysql client?
One way or the other you will face the problem that you cannot cast two selected fields to a User. Reduce your HQL query to `from  User  where email = :email and password = :password1`

Comment: @ rostbot, I have set what you have suggest me..Now I am getting error:-- java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to com.news.User--In database I have the fuser_id as bigint datatype..and in user.java I have id as long.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion with your first or your second example? I would only expect it to work with the second. Additionally it would be helpful to see your hibernate mapping.